# Console.WriteLine((char) 146) appears as "?"

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, console-application

I tried to print this character `’` using `Console.WriteLine((char) 146);` but it printed `?`. When I set `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` it printed some glitched characters, not the one I needed.

Comment: You probably can't change the console encoding programmatically that way. The Windows console is generally useless for Unicode.

Comment: And what do you expect to be printed?

Comment: Have you considered changing your console font to one that has a glyph for that character?

Comment: @user2886646 does my solution work for you now, as still it is not signed as answered?

Comment: Guess it works, but for some reason you are not going to mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is 8217.

But you also have to enable UTF8 encoding and change font, to the one which can display UTF8 characters:

```
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        int value = '’';

        Console.WriteLine((char)value);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

And if your current console font doesnt support this character you may also have to change it.

How?
After you launch the console right-click on the title bar -> properties -> fonts -> Lucida Console

And voila it works!

Comment: What encoding do I need to print ASCII table?

Comment: probably `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`?

Comment: when I try this with `(char)36` I get `$`

Comment: I can get $ with (char)36 too, but still I get "?" when trying to print (char)146

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should help you more now.

Comment: The OP's character isn't a backtick, but a high-nine single quote.

Comment: @Tafari Doesn't work with character code 146

Comment: @user2886646 use my code and change the console font it will work for value 8217.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((char)39);
    }
```

At least this works for me.

Comment: It doesn't change if I add Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; before.

Comment: Are you sure it prints `acute accent (’)` not an `apostrophe (')`? As probably you mix them up.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Seems like I've mixed them up. Sorry! ;)